# Text width is varied Between Displaying panel and print in c#

Tags: c#, printing, gdi+

To draw the Text on panel using Graphics with Font size is 8 pixel, Then Take the Printout using PrintDocument. But Text Width isnt equal, compare to panel and Sheet. around 5 mm width variation occurred.How to solve this problem..?

Comment: Could you provide some code? How are you creating this Font, how are you drawing it on the Panel? Also, why are you drawing on the Panel in the first place, why not a Graphics object?

Comment: _Then Take the Printout_ What does that mean?? Did you set the Dpi of the Graphics object you print with? Also: How and what did you print? Longer text or a few characters?

Comment: This is just a fact, text rendering is not resolution independent.  To make text more readable on a low resolution monitor, the renderer stretches text to make the stems of letters coincide with the pixel grid.  That happens on a high resolution printer (usually 6 times better) to a much lower degree.  Makes for highly readable text but of course the width won't be the same.  If you want an exact match then you need WPF and ensure it renders in "Ideal" mode.  Draws complaints from users btw, they don't like the fuzzy text.